# Get correct token position in golangci-lint private plugin

Tags: go, golangci-lint

Created a custom [plugin](https://golangci-lint.run/contributing/new-linters/#create-a-plugin) for `golangci-lint` linter which just verifies imports in the `go.mod` file against the whitelisted ones. Now, if linter finds a disallowed dependency it reports:

```
goModPath := filepath.Join(modRoot, "go.mod")
data, err := os.ReadFile(goModPath)
if err != nil {
// ...
}

modFile, err := modfile.Parse("go.mod", data, nil)
if err != nil {
// ...
}

for _, req := range modFile.Require {
    isAllowed := false
    for _, allowed := range config.AllowedDependencies {
        if strings.HasPrefix(req.Mod.Path, allowed) {
            isAllowed = true
            break
        }
    }

    if !isAllowed {
        pass.Reportf(pass.Files[0].Package, "dependency '%s' is not in the list of allowed dependencies", req.Mod.Path)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this report will point to the base package and looks like something like this:

> logging/gcp.go:1:1: dependency 'cloud.google.com/go/logging' is not in the list of allowed dependencies

**How can I get token position from the `modFile.Require` (`req`) that it will point to the corresponding line of the `go.mod` file where found disallowed report?**

Tried this way also:

```
startPos := req.Syntax.Start.Byte
pos := token.Pos(startPos)
pass.Reportf(pos, "dependency '%s' is not in the list of allowed dependencies", req.Mod.Path)
```

However, it doesn't help much. Getting this report:

> $GOROOT/src/internal/race/norace.go:43:27: dependency 'cloud.google.com/go/logging' is not in the list of allowed dependencies

Any idea how this can be fixed? Thanks.